# Unable to locate package python-crypto,pysqlite2

Tags: python

I am running below command:

```
-sudo apt-get install sed wget curl cvs subversion git-core coreutils unzip texi2html texinfo docbook-utils gawk python-pysqlite2 diffstat help2man make gcc build-essential g++ desktop-file-utils chrpath libxml2-utils xmlto docbook bsdmainutils iputils-ping cpio python-wand python-pycryptopp python-crypto
```

But this command is giving errors. What am I doing wrong?
error is here-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB7QZ.png)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'git' instead of 'git-core'
E: Unable to locate package python-pysqlite2
E: Unable to locate package python-pycryptopp
E: Unable to locate package python-crypto
```

Comment: You are trying to install some really old packages, which may not be available anymore. Package prefixed with `python-` are Python2 packages. Python 2 is end of life since Jan 1st 2020... so it's outdated. pysqlite2 is I guess a module for SQLite2? Which is outdated for a really long time now - Sqlite 3 is the current version for years now.

Comment: My python3 command is `import sqlite3` First line is: `#!/usr/bin/python3`